# Using Express module as middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Express and trying to use middleware to handle a POST request. If I expose the endpoint, and make a request to the API, everything works fine.

---

#### Working Correctly

*api/index.js*

```
app.post('/api/endpoint', (req, res, next) => {
    next();
});
```

*server.js*

```
app.use(function() {
    console.log('hello'); // => hello
});
```

---

But when I try to replace the middleware function with a module that exports a function, the function never gets invoked.

---

#### Not Working

*api/index.js*

```
app.post('/api/endpoint', (req, res, next) => {
    next();
});
```

*server.js*

```
const makeExternalRequest = require('./server/makeExternalRequest');

...

console.log(makeExternalRequest, typeof makeExternalRequest);
// => [Function] 'function'    

app.use(makeExternalRequest);
```

*server/makeExternalRequest.js*

```
module.exports = function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('hello', err);
}
```

---

The function in *server/makeExternalRequest.js* is never invoked, and nothing logs... Am I using `app.use(...)` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express middleware requires three arguments, the third of which is a function you call when you're done to move the request along to the next handler:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('hello');
  next();
};
```

Without calling the third parameter, your request will just remain pending and a response will never be sent. Also, be sure you call app.use before any handler that would return the response. If the response is sent first, then your middleware will never be reached.

Comment: How do you explain 'hello' being logged in the first example, then?

Comment: Are you mounting the middleware in the same sequence in both cases?

Comment: I am mounting them in the same place.

Comment: Looks like I had accidentally included extra arguments to the module. Your assertion that having the correct number of arguments was correct, after all. I'll mark it accordingly.